# python3 download newest link in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, sorting, beautifulsoup, download

In my python script I loaded a webpage with Beautiful Soup. How can I download only the latest  (newest) file?

```
  <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15012021.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15012021.zip</a>       2021-01-19 06:56  3.6M
  <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15022021.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15022021.zip</a>       2021-02-15 21:57  3.6M
  <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15102020.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15102020.zip</a>       2020-10-24 03:19  3.6M
  <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15112020.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15112020.zip</a>       2020-11-15 15:02  3.6M
  <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15122020.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15122020.zip</a>       2020-12-15 13:48  3.6M
```

The actual url of the page is [https://extracten.bag.kadaster.nl/lvbag/extracten/Gemeente LVC/0498/](https://extracten.bag.kadaster.nl/lvbag/extracten/Gemeente%20LVC/0498/)

Comment: can you give the actual html for above as the dates are no within any tags. actual html they are in some tag then just gab them first and extract those strings to a list. Then convert each date into a separate list of year, month and day. Then compare year if two years are equal compare there months and take most recent month and if two months are equal compare days and take a recent one. For grabbing the link also extract link from the href attribute of corresponding <a> tags and keep dates and links related. So, when you find lowest date grab related link and download! Hope that is solution!

Comment: Which do you consider the latest? Using the filename or the last modified tag?

Comment: Grab the link text strings and sort them, then take the largest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the filename to decide the order then you first need to extract the date and convert it into a `datetime` object. Build a list of the filenames and then sort them using this date. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

html = """<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /lvbag/extracten/Gemeente LVC/0498</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /lvbag/extracten/Gemeente LVC/0498</h1>
<pre>      <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                           <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <hr>      <a href="/lvbag/extracten/Gemeente%20LVC/">Parent Directory</a>                                    -   
      <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15012021.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15012021.zip</a>       2021-01-19 06:56  3.6M  
      <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15022021.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15022021.zip</a>       2021-02-15 21:57  3.6M  
      <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15102020.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15102020.zip</a>       2020-10-24 03:19  3.6M  
      <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15112020.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15112020.zip</a>       2020-11-15 15:02  3.6M  
      <a href="BAGGEM0498L-15122020.zip">BAGGEM0498L-15122020.zip</a>       2020-12-15 13:48  3.6M  
<hr></pre>
</body></html>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
files = []

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = a['href']
    
    if '.zip' in href:
        date = datetime.strptime(href.split('.')[0].split('-')[1], '%d%m%Y')
        files.append([date, href])

files.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print("Latest:", files[0][1])
```

This would give you:

```
Latest: BAGGEM0498L-15022021.zip
```

---

The zip file can be automatically downloaded as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://extracten.bag.kadaster.nl/lvbag/extracten/Gemeente%20LVC/0498/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
files = []

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = a['href']
    
    if '.zip' in href:
        date = datetime.strptime(href.split('.')[0].split('-')[1], '%d%m%Y')
        files.append([date, href])

files.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
filename = files[0][1]
print("Latest:", filename)

# Download the zip file

with open(filename, 'wb') as f_zip:
    r_zip = requests.get(f'{url}{filename}')
    f_zip.write(r_zip.content)
```